# Microsoft Teams Application Authorization: ngrok gateway error The server returned an invalid or incomplete HTTP response

Tags: npm, active-directory, microsoft-teams, ngrok, microsoft-graph-teams

Summary:
I am currently building a Microsoft Teams application with Outlook API support for sending messages within teams. In order to make these calls I am setting up Authentication using the Microsoft graphs methodology. I am currently following this tutorial: https://github.com/aycabas/TeamsApp
I am able to get through all of the steps with setting up authentication but when attempting to load the application in teams I am met with this error: `ngrok gateway error The server returned an invalid or incomplete HTTP response.`

What I've tried:
I have tried setting up NPM and ngrok for tunneling multiple times. I have verified that my link are correct and valid according to app registrations. I am able to access the project locally through the browser but not within the teams application.

Code:
auth.js:
```import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './components/App';
import { Provider, themes } from '@fluentui/react-northstar'
//https://fluentsite.z22.web.core.windows.net/quick-start

````
ReactDOM.render(
<Provider theme={themes.teams}>
    <App />
</Provider>, document.getElementById('auth')
); ``

auth.html:
```<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='main.css'>
<script src='main.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="auth"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@microsoft/teams-js/dist/MicrosoftTeams.min.js" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@microsoft/mgt/dist/bundle/mgt-loader.js"></script>
<script>
    mgt.TeamsProvider.handleAuth();
</script>
</body>
</html> ```
````

Thanks!

Comment: If you're wanting to using mgt with react, rather consider https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/mgt-react

Comment: where are you seeing the ngrok error?

Comment: In the teams application, it says it makes connection but the server returned an invalid or incomplete HTTP response.

Comment: Can you please post your ngrok screen (if it has any error). 
Please verify if your app and ngrok is on same port and make sure ngrok is updated in manifest in tab url and valid domains has "*.ngrok.io"

Comment: The only message it returns is "Makes connection but the server returned an invalid or incomplete", all of the above is correct, hence the connection succeeding but not giving a response.

Comment: Could you please try re-installing the bot within the team and re-triggering the event, this should fix the issue.